# Not equal query in hql not work

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am tring the 'not equal' query in hql.

```
 @Override
    public Student findStudentsByYear(String year) {
        String queryString = "from Student where year<>:year ";
        Query query =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);        
        query.setParameter("year", year);
        return (Student)query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

but it is not working properly.How to write this query correctly

My student table is

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| studentId   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| course      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dob         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| faculty     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| firstName   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| homeAddress | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| linkedIn    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| university  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_userId | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Define "it is not work properly". Precisely. Paste the complete stack trace you get, and post the code used to execute that query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know it's late but if anyone is having similar problem, you can use this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("year", year));
List<Student> result = criteria.list();
```

Or this:

```
List<Student> result = session.createQuery ("from Student where year!=:year").setParameter("year", year).list();
```

I'm not sure what the problem is in above example as Samantha did not provide any information what so ever but my guess is that the `uniqueResult()` is causing trouble because this query returns a list and not one result.